# How to use SELECT INTO with static values included?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select-into

I'd like to add a value to the values provided by a SELECT INTO statement.

Given the table named foo:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
+----+
```

I would like to populate the table bar with:

```
+----+------+
| id | type |
+----+------+
| 1  | R    |
| 2  | R    |
| 3  | R    |
+----+------+
```

I'd imagine this looking something like this:

```
SELECT foo.id, type INTO bar FROM foo LEFT JOIN 'R' AS type;
```

... unfortunately this doesn't work. Can anyone tell me how to do this please

I'm using both mysql and mssql

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT foo.id, 'R' AS type INTO bar FROM foo;
```

In MySQL this would normally be done with:

Lazy with no indexes

```
CREATE TABLE bar SELECT id, 'R' AS type FROM foo;
```

Nicer way (assuming you've created table `bar` already)

```
INSERT INTO bar SELECT id, 'R' AS type FROM foo;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT foo.id
     , 'R'
INTO bar (id, type)
FROM foo
```

For MySQL use:

```
INSERT INTO bar (id, type)
  SELECT foo.id
       , 'R'
  FROM foo
```